# How to optimize this grammar rule?

Tags: grammar, tatsu

I am implementing a grammar using the TatSu python library. My grammar is working OK but there is one rule that is eating quite a bit of time. On a block of around 3000 lines (part of a bigger grammar), if I take this full rule, it takes about 42s to parse the entire block. If I reduce this rule to just a few tokens, the runtime drops from 42s to 33s (~20% improvement).

The rule is shown below and it should match a series of *event* separated by the '/'.

```
events
    =
    '/'%{event}
    ;
event
    =
    'D' | 'U' | 'Z' | 'P' | 'L' | 'H' | 'x' | 'X' | 'T' | 'V' | 'l' | 'h' | 't' | 'v' | 'N' | 'A' | 'B' | 'F' | '?' | 'G' | 'R' | 'Q' | 'M'
    | 'ForceDown' | 'ForceUp' | 'ForceOff' | 'ForcePrior' | 'CompareLow' | 'CompareHigh' | 'CompareUnknown' | 'CompareOff'
    | 'CompareValid' | 'CompareLowWindow' | 'CompareHighWindow' | 'CompareOffWindow' | 'CompareValidWindow' | 'ForceUnknown'
    | 'LogicLow' | 'LogicHigh' | 'LogicZ' | 'Unknown' | 'ExpectHigh' | 'ExpectLow' | 'ExpectOff' | 'Marker'
    ;
```

If I change *event* to the following, I get faster parsing.

```
event
  =
  /[DUZPLHXT]/
  ;
```

So is it possible to improve the rule above in some way to get faster processing? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, for a rule with many options which are just tokens it's much more efficient to use patterns (regular expressions).

But runtime ultimately depends on how some rules call upon each other.

A simple optimization you can try is to add a cut (`˜`) expression so each `event` is tried at most once (although a *cut* should be implicit in the `%` expression).

```ml
event
    =
    (
    'D' | 'U' | 'Z' | 'P' | 'L' | 'H' | 'x' | 'X' | 'T' | 'V' | 'l' | 'h' | 't' | 'v' | 'N' | 'A' | 'B' | 'F' | '?' | 'G' | 'R' | 'Q' | 'M'
    | 'ForceDown' | 'ForceUp' | 'ForceOff' | 'ForcePrior' | 'CompareLow' | 'CompareHigh' | 'CompareUnknown' | 'CompareOff'
    | 'CompareValid' | 'CompareLowWindow' | 'CompareHighWindow' | 'CompareOffWindow' | 'CompareValidWindow' | 'ForceUnknown'
    | 'LogicLow' | 'LogicHigh' | 'LogicZ' | 'Unknown' | 'ExpectHigh' | 'ExpectLow' | 'ExpectOff' | 'Marker'
    ) ~
    ;
```

That said, because the rule is so much of the *lexical* kind, I'd opt for the regular expression.

```ml
event
    =
    /(?x)
    'D' | 'U' | 'Z' | 'P' | 'L' | 'H' | 'x' | 'X' | 'T' | 'V' | 'l' | 'h' | 't' | 'v' | 'N' | 'A' | 'B' | 'F' | '?' | 'G' | 'R' | 'Q' | 'M'
    | 'ForceDown' | 'ForceUp' | 'ForceOff' | 'ForcePrior' | 'CompareLow' | 'CompareHigh' | 'CompareUnknown' | 'CompareOff'
    | 'CompareValid' | 'CompareLowWindow' | 'CompareHighWindow' | 'CompareOffWindow' | 'CompareValidWindow' | 'ForceUnknown'
    | 'LogicLow' | 'LogicHigh' | 'LogicZ' | 'Unknown' | 'ExpectHigh' | 'ExpectLow' | 'ExpectOff' | 'Marker'
    /
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you. With this fix, I am able to get a consistent runtime of around 32-33s for my testcase.

Comment: ~ 30s still sounds like a lot. Consider adding cut expressions where a rule should commit to a given option.